# Yalmip communicating with Matlab Quadprog, Setting options

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, solver

I face problem with setting options of [Quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/quadprog.html) solver through [Yalmip](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/), .

```
Options = sdpsettings('solver','quadprog','quadprog.Algorithm', ... 
                      'interior-point-convex','quadprog.Display', ...
                      'iter','quadprog.Diagnostics', 'on');
diagnostics = solvesdp(Constraints , Objective, Options);
```

But none of these option settings work. In particular, it does not display the progress iteratively. The documentation, or FAQ did not help much either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a consistent solver-agnostic way to control display level, it is always controlled through the **verbose** option. Set it to 2 and you will set the iteration display options. Before the call to quadprog, the code inside YALMIP looks like this

```
switch options.verbose
case 0
    options.quadprog.Display = 'off';
case 1
    options.quadprog.Display = 'final';
otherwise
    options.quadprog.Display = 'iter';
end
```

Having said that, it will not get you any further. In recent version of MATLAB, they have removed the iteration display for some bizarre reason. If you read the help on quadprog, it states  *Currently, only 'final' and 'off' are valid values for the parameter Display ('iter' is not available).*

Finally, if you are in academia and some anything but minor QPs, install a better QP solver. Quadprog is mediocre at best. Solvers such as cplex, gurobi, xpress and mosek all have (full functionality) free academic versions.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/quadprog.html#inputarg_options) states that "the interior-point algorithm allows additional values" (including 'iter', 'iter-detailed', and 'final-detailed')

Comment: Correct, the following options would show iterations

sdpsettings('solver','quadprog','verbose',2,'quadprog.Algorithm','interior-point-convex')